# Get an progress output for Export-VM

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I recently created a script that's able to create a chosen number of Hyper-V VMs from a "template", by exporting one VM and import it with different ids and names.

Everything is working smoothly, but the export takes quite some time. Is there any way to get an progress output from the export-vm? If I look in the hyper-v command center, I see that my VM is exported after i started the script, and it has a progress value, too, so somehow there seems to be a way to get the current progress...

It would also be nice to have a progress output for Import-VM, too, but that's not really important.

---

If you are interested, here is my current script. I know that the hard-coded paths and other ascpects aren't really nice, so please don't tell me anything about code style or something like this. First comes a working script, then comes nice code.

```
param(
[int]$Anzahl = 0,
[string]$BasisVM = 'Schulung',
[string]$ExportDir = 'C:\VMConf\Export\',
[string]$ExportConf = 'Schulung\Virtual Machines\0D444AF2-3E63-4ACF-867E-34440AA99C42.xml',
[string]$VMDir = 'C:\VMs\',
[string]$VMNamePrefix = 'Schulung'
)

if ($Anzahl -eq 0) {
    $Anzahl = Read-Host "Bitte Anzahl der benötigten VMs eingeben"
}

"`nStarte Export der Vorlage..."

if (-Not(Test-Path $ExportDir)) {
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $ExportDir | out-null
}
Export-VM -Name $BasisVM -Path $ExportDir

"Abgeschlossen.`n"

if (Test-Path $VMDir) {
    $err = $null
    $i = 1
    while (-not($err)) {
        if ($i -gt 1) {
            "Alte VM Nummer $($i - 1) wurde gelöscht."
        }
        Remove-VM -Name $($VMNamePrefix + ("{0:D2}" -f $i)) -Force -ErrorVariable err -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $i++  
    }

    Remove-Item -r $VMDir | out-null
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $VMDir | out-null
}

"`n$Anzahl VMs werden erstellt..."

for ($i=1; $i -le $Anzahl; $i++) {
"`tErstelle VM Nummer $i..."

$name = ($VMNamePrefix + ("{0:D2}" -f $i))
$path = ($VMDir + $name)

$VM = Import-VM -Path $($ExportDir + $ExportConf) -VhdDestinationPath $($path + "/Virtual Hard Discs") -VirtualMachinePath $path -Copy -GenerateNewId
Rename-VM -VM $VM -NewName $name

"`t$VM Nummer $i wurde erzeugt."
}

"Abgeschlossen.`n"

"Aufräumen..."
if (Test-Path $ExportDir) {
    Remove-Item -r $ExportDir | out-null
}
"Abgeschlossen."
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could start the export (and even imports) as a background job and then log the progress of the job. Sample code:

```
$ExportJob = Export-VM -Name $BasisVM -Path $ExportDir -AsJob;

while( $ExportJob.State -eq "Running" -or $ExportJob.State -eq "NotStarted") 
{
    Write-Output ("[Export] " + $($ExportJob.Progress.PercentComplete) + "% complete");
    sleep(5);
}

if($ExportJob.State -ne "Completed")
{
    Write-Error ("Export Job did not complete: " +$ExportJob.State);
    throw $ExportJob.Error;
}
```

Comment: i now used write-progress instead of write-output: `Write-Progress -activity "VM wird Exportiert" -status "Fortschritt:" -percentCompelte $ExportJob.Progress.PercentComplete`

Comment: How does the script know how much % has been completed? Is that something that Export-VM produces?